# Creating MSI files with GitHub Actions (YML)

Tags: github, yaml, github-actions

I have a Visual Studio 2017 project that has C++, C#, C++/CLI and Installers …
all the projects load but the installers (vdproj projects ) do not build …

```
name: xxx-github-actions
on: [push]
jobs:
build-release-configuration:
runs-on: self-hosted
steps:

name: checkout
uses: actions/checkout@v3
uses: actions/setup-node@v3
with:
node-version: ‘14’
name: Add msbuild to Path
uses: microsoft/setup-msbuild@v1
with:
vswhere-path: ‘C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer’
vs-version: ‘[15.9,16.0)’
  - uses: nuget/setup-nuget@v1
    with:
     nuget-version: 4.7.1
  - run: nuget restore xxx.project.sln  
    
  - run: msbuild xxx.project.sln  /p:Configuration=Release /p:Platform=x64
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to accomplish this - by using DevEnv.com ...

```
run: .\DevEnv.com "xxx.project.sln " /rebuild "Release|x64"
working-directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE
```